# Could not get Return Value from a Function ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello everyone i have some trouble returning a result from a function , 
i made a select input  with `ng-change` the result of `ng-change` is used by an API then displays the result in a table the issue is i can't use the result out of  the function

**Here's my html page**

```
        <select ng-model="dvdv"  ng-change="update()" class="form-control" >
        <option value="" disabled selected>Veuillez sélectionner un DVD</option>
        <option  ng-repeat="d in dvd"  value="{{d}}"> {{d}} </option>
        </select>
```

**The table were data should be displayed**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" >
        <thead><tr class="infoti" >
        <th>Id Dev</th>
        <th>Nom Dev </th>
        <th>Nom Ecu</th>
        <th>Etat</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
   <tr dir-paginate=" dev in devs | itemsPerPage:7| filter: search">
            <td>{{dev[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{dev[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{dev[2]}}</td>
            <td>Non Validé</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default">Validé</button></td>
           </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**and this is the Function am using to get the data from select input by `ng-change` and am consuming**

```
$scope.devs=[[]]
$scope.update=function(){

  console.log($scope.dvdv)
  $http.get("/dev?nommag="+$scope.dvdv)
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.devs = data ;
      console.log($scope.devs)
    })
}
```

here's a pic to explain how i want it to work

[image]

when i select an option i get the data then displayed but it's not printed in the table below 
else it work for a static so there's no issue with the syntax or ng-repeat

Comment: `$http.get()` is an asynchronous call. When you print `$scope.devs` outside the request is empty because it prints before the call has finished.

Comment: so if i can't use it outside how can i display the data !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @KamelMili You can use the data because when it is available and you update `devs` angulars data binding takes over and updates the view. On a side note `.success()` is deprecated. Use `.then()` instead.

Comment: @ste2425 it's still don't work :/

Comment: Does anyone has an idea about $timeout i think mayebe itis the solution

Comment: Can you elaborate on the parameter passed to filter filter: search. Where is this object created. I guess it is empty and that is causing the table to be empty

Comment: no am passing it in the input ng-model="search"

Answer (score -1):

If by 'use' you do mean `console.log()`, you must do in **inside** the success callback (as @ddepablo suggests).
If instead by 'use' you do mean "show it in the html page", you simply put a

```
{{ devs }}
```

inside your html page, and angular will replace it with `$scope.devs` value...

Comment: it's an array of array and am using it and it's not working outside in the html Page

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working outside in the html Page"? Can you post an example of your usage of `$scope.devs`?

Comment: it's posted in the question the table that am displaying data with

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working outside in the html Page"?

Comment: In the table in html page its not displaying the data from the get